# angularJS directive to handle differences in view based on search results?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My AngularJS app has a landing page with a search input and a search-type multi-choice select. When a visitor enters a search and clicks GO the app routes to the results view.

Now the view will be a little different based on what they chose in the search-type drop-down. They might chose to search for a person or place or company.

How do I make the view handle the differences based on the search type. The view is a ng- repeat of the results. If the search type is a place then the address. If it's a person then the title is the name.

I think my view needs to become a directive but I haven't seen examples of this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXivnFK6VSBGYCeZwyAs?p=preview) that demonstrates how you can execute different routes based on the selection in an `options` list.  This approach let's you define different controllers, scopes and templates for each of your search categories.

**Update**
[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktMVZ) that illustrates using a service that can be injected into a controller to provide category specific searches

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.factory("searchService", function() {
    return {
        doSearch: function(query, category) {
         return "searching for '" + query + "' in category '" + category + "'";   
        }
    };
});

function demo($scope, searchService) {
    $scope.search = function() {
        $scope.results = searchService.doSearch($scope.query, $scope.searchCategory);
    }
};
```

Comment: I went in this direction but it means duplicate code. I hope to find a dynamic solution.

Comment: here's an example of using a service to execute searches: http://jsfiddle.net/ktMVZ/